# How to use background image with bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, responsive-design

I have a background image that is very large 1600 X 3700. I need to add bootstrap to my project and every time i do my background image disappears and only the first 100px of my background image shows.  What is the proper way to use bootstrap with a background image.  This is what i am using so far

```
html{ background: url('image-path.png') no-repeat; -webkit-   background-size: cover;-moz-background-size: cover;-o-background-size: cover; background-size: cover;}
```

Comment: mind creating a jsfiddle or a demo of the issue?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tgpz92ra/#&togetherjs=zMf73r4JIq  When i use js fiddle i seem to have no issues.  But when i am using it locally via WAMP my background image gets all messed up.

Comment: It does the same even if i dont use an image..if i just use a background color and add bootstrap it does the exact same thing.

Comment: ah i figured it out...i used body instead of html and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
position:fixed;
top:0;
bottom:0;
```